# AVA testing gives undefined when importing to test.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, ava

I am using AVA as testing with node and javascript.

On test.js

```
import test from 'ava';
import {valid, output, input} from './dependency.js';

test("Input is not a Empty String", t => {
    t.not(input, ''); t.pass();
})

test("Correct output", t => {
    var testInput = ['KittenService: CameCaser', 'CamelCaser: '];
    var expected = 'CamelCaser, KittenService';
    var actual = output;
    t.deepEqual(actual, expected, "Result did match");
})
```

On first test it passes even though my

> var input = '';

Also on my second test it throws:

```
t.deepEqual(actual, expected, "Result did match")
              |       |
              |       "CamelCaser, KittenService"
              undefined
```

on dependency.js

```
module.exports = {valid, input, output};
var input = '';
var output = [];
```

I do have value of output after function but it seems like on test.js it doesn't take either input or output value from dependency test.
I am not exactly sure how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVA uses Babel to compile the import statements. Since `dependency.js` isn't created using Babel the `module.exports` object is treated as a *default* export when importing.

Do this instead:

```
import test from 'ava';
import dependency from './dependency.js';

const {valid, output, input} = dependency;

test("Input is not a Empty String", t => {
    t.not(input, '');
})

test("Correct output", t => {
    var testInput = ['KittenService: CameCaser', 'CamelCaser: '];
    var expected = 'CamelCaser, KittenService';
    var actual = output;
    t.deepEqual(actual, expected, "Result did match");
})
```

P.S. You usually do not need `t.pass()`.

Comment: Hey Mark I changed the code and it is giving me same result.

Comment: My package.json code

`{
  "name": "assessment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^0.17.0"
  }
}`

Comment: Figured out I had to put my variables inside the dependency function then your method worked.